# Running some javascript code before rendering in a list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some data I am receiving from the server. The data is an array of image objects with no explicit key and I can read it in javascript like this:

```
var images_obj = response.data.room_photos;
images_obj.forEach((url, index) => {
console.log('Index: ' + index + ' Url: ' + url.url);
});
```

The data is in this format:

```
[ { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aaaaefd.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aaa9dc2.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aab1252.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aab147a.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aab0226.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aaaf92b.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3aaec480.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab3a61b.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab432cb.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab00b91.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab02040.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab43f3e.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab3a634.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab4729f.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab47168.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab7af65.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab7dae1.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab8738f.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab86f15.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab8af48.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ab95423.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abbbdf9.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abc455e.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abca83e.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abca0a0.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abcfa7a.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3abd9d73.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ac09a00.jpg" }, { "url": "/var/www/html/uploads/609cd3ac1382f.jpg" } ]
```

I want to render the images in a carousel  and I can do it like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    {{roomsData.room_photos}}
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" v-for="value in roomsData.room_photos">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" :src="value" alt="First slide">
      {{value.url}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
    </div>
```

However, the image url object is an absolute url of an ubuntu box so I only need the last part i.e `609cd3aab147a.jpg` for each url. How can I run some javascript to grab and display the last part which I also need to concatenate with my website i.e `https://example.com/uploads/609cd3aab147a.jpg`

I would also like to generate an index that I can target when deleting an image.

Comment: What is your question? How when to run some code? What exactly the code should be? or generating an index? Please ask one specific question per post

Comment: Use [Computed Properties](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Comment: The question is, how do i grab the last part of the absolute url returned? Should i reform the in javascript and have it ready there, or can i just do this from within the vue js looping. I am able to generate the index in pure javascript and also access the value.

Comment: @TJ UIts not two questions in one!! To fully explain for your needs, is it possible to run a js code at this level v-for="value in roomsData.room_photos"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you bind data fetched from API to view-model, do the transformation you want, example:

```js
this.roomsData.room_photos = response.data.room_photos.map(item => {
  let url_parts = item.url.split('/')
  return location.origin + '/' + url_parts[url_parts.length - 1]
})
```

Comment: How can i set an index that can be accessed in the reformed object. In vue {{value}} gives me the last part but i would like also to access the index. I want to access like  `v-for="(value,index) in roomsData.room_photos"`

Comment: You can access index as you wrote. From Vue documentation: _"`v-for` also supports an optional second argument for the index of the current item."_ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the response and generate a new array from the provided objects.

```
const images_obj = response.data.room_photos.reduce((images, photo) => {
  images[] = { url: photo.url.split('/').pop() }

  return images
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the image name.

`let url = "/id/118/200/300.jpg";`

`let filename = url.split('/').pop().split('?')[0];`

Reference link : https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/how-to-get-the-filename-from-url-in-javascript.htm